# How to provide a twisted reactor which is currently running?

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

We are trying to program a bot which claim to crawl articles from a newspaper thanks it's rss feeds. 
So we want that our script could repeat this steps several times per day:

1) look at the rss feeds we have listed

2) identify articles we haven't crawled yet

3) add the links to a list of urls to crawl

4) crawl the urls listed

We achieve to execute these steps one time with this code:

```
rss_feeds_lemonde = [
'http://www.lemonde.fr/rss/une.xml',
'http://www.lemonde.fr/international/rss_full.xml',
'http://www.lemonde.fr/politique/rss_full.xml',
]

db = sqlite3.connect('newspaper_db')
cursor = db.cursor()
urls = []
already_met = False
site = 'lemonde'

for rss_feed in rss_feeds_lemonde:
    parsed_rss_feed = feedparser.parse(rss_feed)
    for post in parsed_rss_feed.entries:
        url = post.link
        if url.split('.')[1] == site:
            cursor.execute('''SELECT url FROM articles WHERE newspaper = site''')
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            for row in rows:
                if row[0] == url:
                    already_met = True
            if already_met == False:
                cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO articles(url, newspaper) VALUES(?,?)''', (url, site))
                urls.append(url)
            else:
                already_met = False

cursor.close()
db.commit()
db.close()
if urls != []:
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(LeMondeSpider, start_urls = urls)
    process.start()
```

The problem is that the twisted reactor is not restartable so it allows us to execute our steps once. Is it possible to pause the reactor and unpause it after we provide a new list of urls to crawl?
Have we other solutions?

[edit] for notorious.no, this example works fine now thanks to you !

```
def run_when_crawl_done(null):
    time.sleep(10)
    urls = [
    'http://www.lefigaro.fr/elections/presidentielles/2017/05/05/35003-20170505ARTFIG00129-comment-ils-veulent-bloquer-le-pen-sans-soutenir-macron-ce-dimanche.php',
    'http://www.lefigaro.fr/elections/presidentielles/2017/05/04/35003-20170504ARTFIG00259-si-marine-le-pen-atteint-40-ca-serait-deja-une-enorme-victoire-dit-sa-niece.php',
    'http://www.lefigaro.fr/elections/presidentielles/2017/05/04/35003-20170504ARTFIG00126-emmanuel-macron-non-je-n-ai-pas-de-compte-aux-bahamas.php',
    ]
    deffered = runner.crawl(LeFigaroSpider, start_urls = urls)
    deffered.addCallback(lambda _: reactor.stop())

urls = [
'http://www.lemonde.fr/les-decodeurs/article/2017/04/26/europe-macron-emploi-la-trumpisation-de-marine-le-pen-sur-tf1_5117479_4355770.html',
'http://www.lemonde.fr/syrie/article/2017/04/26/attaque-chimique-la-france-avance-ses-preuves-contre-damas_5117652_1618247.html',
]

if urls != []:
    configure_logging()
    runner = CrawlerRunner()
    deferred = runner.crawl(LeMondeSpider, start_urls = urls)
    deferred.addCallback(run_when_crawl_done)
    reactor.run()
```

Comment: AFAIK twister reactor is global so you can just import it and do whatever you want with it. However looking at your code I don't think that's what you want to do. Usually people approach this issue with good ol' crontabs. Schedule `cd project && scrapy crawl spider` to run every 8 hours and you're good to go! If you want more of an atomic url distribution I suggest looking into redis or more specifically [`scrapy-redis`](https://github.com/rolando/scrapy-redis)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In fact, we want to do a script that we execute once and that repeat our loop (every two hours for example) until we stop the script running manually. Our loop consist in doing steps 1 to 4 we explained above. But is it possible to provide a crawl to a twisted reactor already opened?

Comment: Why though? Having a loop running for extensive period of time is almost always a bad idea, just a cron or systemd job.

Comment: I'm a noob in programing so I do not understand everything well. Please could you explain when it can be a bad idea? You are right for the cron, but ideally if there is another solution not too complicated it will be better because we want re-use the program and upgrade it on other computers later. Thanks for your time granted to answer our issue.

Comment: Do not use `time.sleep` this is a blocking call and will block the reactor until the sleep is over

Comment: I used it to try if I can force the reactor to wait until crawling another task, I'm not sure I will it use in my final script but it works well. Is there specific reasons to avoid this instruction?

Comment: Because `time.sleep` is not async function and will block the reactor/event loop from executing other tasks. Recall that async frameworks run in a single thread and simply break the jobs into small executions. Each execution is essentially "blocking" the reactor, but finishes so quickly that it seems like nothing is blocking. Please visit [Twisted's site](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/index.html), or any other aysnc framework for insight into async design patterns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twisted's reactor is indeed unable to restart. If you think about it for a minute, you will realize that stopping an event loop, only to have another event start it back up, is counter intuitive. Most event driven apps are "long running" and should not stop unless something is severely wrong.

Do not start-stop-restart event loops. Start the app and then never restart it (you're making a bot so I assume that the bot never sleeps). Use `CrawlerRunner` instead of `CrawlerProcess` then execute `reactor.run()`. This allows a bit more flexibility and allows you to run more tasks concurrently.

```
def run_when_crawl_done(null):
    """
    logic that will be executed after the crawl is done
    """

if urls:
    runner = CrawlerRunner()
    deferred = runner.crawl(LeMondeSpider, start_urls=urls)
    deferred.addCallback(run_when_crawl_done)
    reactor.run()
```

Comment: Indeed the bot never sleeps, so if I understand well: we can repeat our loop when one is finished thanks runner.addCallback(run_when_crawl_done) by defining run_when_crawl_down as our loop?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, this is an error on my part. `runner.crawl()` returns a [`Deferred`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html#callbacks) which you can then chain callback functions to. `run_when_crawl_done` is an example of a callback function that runs after a crawl is completed. I've updated the code example in the answer. As far as the `reactor`, there's only 1 of them so you can simply do `from twisted.internet import reactor` and simply call the reactor functions as desired.

Comment: I've made a test with your method but the problem is that it opens my first spider and instead of crawling it's set of urls it opens the second spider I've put in my callback function and then crawls the two sets of urls in the same time. That's what we don't want. We want the first set of urls to be crawled and then look for another set of urls and crawl it. Thank you for the help.

Comment: There are a few reasons why that might be happening. You will need to provide your new code for me to effectively help you. Simply update your question and append the new code without removing the original question.

Comment: It's logical because the callback function is executed just after deferred and the problem is that deffered is executed before reactor.run(). So is there a way to execute our loop in the reactor.run() before it stops?

Comment: Notice how in my example I provide **only** the name of function `run_when_carwl_done` for the callback, as opposed to "calling it" directly ie. `run_when_crawl_done()`. When you do this the function gets called right away. Change `addCallback(run_when_crawl_done())` to `addCallback(run_when_crawl_done)` and the function will get called after the first scrape is completed. I figured this is what you were doing wrong :D its a common mistake.

Comment: That error occurs when you do `reactor.run()` multiple times. It should only once.

Comment: Exactly :p thank you very much! now it works perfectly! Yes I've just deleted it ^^

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to have a python loop running and acting as a crawling scheduler (which is not a very good idea generally) you should use `subprocess` module to spawn some crawling process:

```
import subprocess
import time

while True:
    subprocess.open('cd project && scrapy crawl spider') 
    time.sleep(60 * 30)
```

All of you sql logic should go in spider itself rather than execution script.